# Unexpected solution when using scipy.optimize.minimize to solve a optimization problem

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to express the following optimization problem in scipy.

[image]

Assuming r is a known array with values:
[0.96366965, 0.93341242, 0.90676733, 0.88186071, 0.8582291,  0.83472442, 0.80977363, 0.783683, 0.75743122, 0.73259614]

```
def objective_function(x):
    e_t = np.zeros(10)
    e_t[0] = 1 - 1 / (1 + r[0])

    for t in range(1, 9):
        sub = 0
        for ti in range(0, t):
            sub += np.sum(x[: (ti + 1)]) / (1 + r[ti]) ** (ti + 1)

        e_t[t] = 1 - 1 / (1 + r[t]) ** (t + 1) - sub

    e_t[9] = 0

    return np.sum(e_t**2)

def constraint_function(t):
    def calculate_et(x):
        sub = 0
        for ti in range(0, t):
            sub += np.sum(x[: (ti + 1)]) / (1 + r[ti]) ** (ti + 1)

        e_t = 1 - 1 / (1 + r[t]) ** (t + 1) - sub
        return e_t

    return calculate_et

x0 = np.zeros(10)
cons = (
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(1)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(2)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(3)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(4)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(5)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(6)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(7)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(8)},
    {"type": "ineq", "fun": constraint_function(9)},
)

result = minimize(
    objective_function,
    x0,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=cons,
)
alpha = result.x

c = np.zeros(10)
c[0] = alpha[0]
for i in range(1, 10):
   c[i] = alpha[i-1] + alpha[i]
```

However, the solution I got was quite off from the expected values, so I'm assuming this is not the right method to solve the problem. What is wrong with my current approach and are there other ways to approach it?

the solution I got for c is [9.02212140e-01 9.02212140e-01 2.39808173e-13 1.06359366e-13
4.57411886e-14 1.75415238e-14 6.16173779e-15 2.17534324e-15
4.67095103e-16 1.25975522e-17]

the expected solution is closer to [0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0320, 0.0325, 0.0336, 0.0353]

Comment: What result did you get, what did you expect, and why did you expect it?

Comment: It seems like you've named alpha `x`, which is a bad idea. Further, alpha should actually be derived from C. Can you provide values for `r`?

Comment: Is C known or not?

Comment: we're trying to solve for alpha, and C can be derived from alpha.

values of r: [0.96366965 0.93341242 0.90676733 0.88186071 0.8582291 0.83472442
 0.80977363 0.783683   0.75743122 0.73259614]

Comment: updated the question to include expected c and known r

Comment: Have you tried using your expected answer as the initial guess?   It could be that starting from the origin falls into a local minimum.  You might need to choose a different minimization method to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your math. With your current objective, the "expected solution" has a much higher objective cost than what `minimize` is able to come up with:

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, NonlinearConstraint


def calculate_e(alpha: np.ndarray, t: np.ndarray, r: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    den = 1/(1 + r[:-1])**t
    inner = alpha[:-2].cumsum() * den[:-1]
    e19 = 1 - den - np.concatenate(([0], inner.cumsum()))
    return np.concatenate((e19, [0]))


def objective_function(alpha: np.ndarray, t: np.ndarray, r: np.ndarray) -> float:
    e = calculate_e(alpha, t, r)
    return e.dot(e)


def main() -> None:
    r = np.array((
        0.96366965, 0.93341242, 0.90676733, 0.88186071, 0.85822910,
        0.83472442, 0.80977363, 0.78368300, 0.75743122, 0.73259614,
    ))
    n = r.size
    t = np.arange(1, n)
    c_expected = np.array((
        0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318, 0.0318,
        0.0318, 0.0320, 0.0325, 0.0336, 0.0353,
    ))
    alpha_expected = np.concatenate((
        c_expected[:1],
        np.diff(c_expected),
    ))

    result = minimize(
        fun=objective_function,
        x0=alpha_expected,
        args=(t, r),
        bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=partial(calculate_e, t=t, r=r),
            lb=0, ub=np.inf,
        ),
        tol=1e-9,
    )
    assert result.success, result.message
    alpha = result.x
    c = alpha.cumsum()

    print(f' Initial cost: {objective_function(alpha_expected, t, r):.2f}')
    print(f'Solution cost: {result.fun:.2f}')
    print('α =')
    print(alpha)
    print('C =')
    print(c)
    print('e =')
    print(calculate_e(alpha, t, r))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
 Initial cost: 6.71
Solution cost: 0.35
α =
[9.05392583e-01 1.38775468e-16 4.16322395e-17 2.77550652e-17
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.10000000e-03 1.70000000e-03]
C =
[0.90539258 0.90539258 0.90539258 0.90539258 0.90539258 0.90539258
 0.90539258 0.90539258 0.90649258 0.90819258]
e =
[4.90749373e-01 2.71411502e-01 1.52473537e-01 8.63851746e-02
 4.87947275e-02 2.68482231e-02 1.36020676e-02 5.32970702e-03
 2.22044605e-16 0.00000000e+00]
```